# Consolidating the attribute data from underlying smaller polygons to a bigger layer on top

Tags: arcmap, polygon

I am using ESRI's ArcMap 10.2

I have an underlying polygon layer made up of small pieces and they have census data attached to them (think of counties for the state of Texas).

I want this data averaged and visible in the attribute table for the larger overlying polygon (think of the state of Texas), therefore I want to have the average census data across these counties visible as one row of data for Texas. E.g, Average income from the overlying counties, averaged out for the entire overlying polygon.

Kinda looks like this:

```
Polygon - AverageIncome - WhiteRace - PeoplePerHousehold

Polygon1 - 24124        - 13410     - 2.6

Polygon1 - 29481        - 25281     - 3.2

Polygon1 - 68128        - 43591     - 4.2
```

And I want it to end up like this for the polygon that covers them:

```
Polygon - AverageIncome - WhiteRace - PeoplePerHousehold

Polygon1 - 40577.6        - 27427     - 3.3
```

For the life of me I have spent hours searching the internet and trying different tools, without a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) state with counties
2. [Dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the results using state name field as Dissolve_Field and Income, WhiteRace and PeoplePerHousehold as Statistics Fields with Mean as Statistics Type
3. Join the results to the State polygon using state name as common field. You can join by right-clicking layer - Joins and relates - Join
4. The join is not permanent so make a copy using [Copy Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm) or right-clicking layer - Data - Export Data

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it does dissolve by the state name, but once I try to get the census data involved I can't run the tool giving ERROR 000369: Invalid input field(s) how can I fix this?

Comment: Are the fields you are using as Statistics field valid? For example not text field with numbers in them? You could also try to run tool Repair Geometry Before dissolve.

Comment: Actually I'm just a fool, didn't input the fields correctly, but it worked!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Spatial Join tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm). Set the join type as one-to-one and change the merge rule for your fields (e.g. mean).